# Fantasy powered individuals including a rare Divine Rage

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a fantasy book that I read at least twenty years ago (late 90s, early 00s). It was a fairly standard medieval fantasy setting, with characters being warriors for various different factions.

Individuals in this setting had hereditary powers that gave them various super-human abilities. The only one that (I think) I remember clearly was "Divine Rage" that enabled the wielder to project his bloodlust outwards across the whole battle field. This was a very rare gift in the setting and it didn't seem very useful as it affected everyone, simply amping up the violence in an already violent setting.

I really don't remember anything else about the setting or plot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly [The Iron Throne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Throne_(Birthright_novel)) by Simon Hawke. It was published in 1995 so it matches the time you remember reading it

[image: The Iron Throne]

There are humans called *The Blooded* who have powers inherited from Gods:

> The god essence the cataclysm had released had been much dissipated when
> it reached them, but the remaining energy had still imbued them with
> abilities no humans had possessed before. In the coming years, these
> wondrous powers would be passed on to their descendants, who would be
> called "the blooded," those who had inherited blood abilities bestowed
> on the survivors of that battle where the gods themselves gave up their
> lives.
>
> ...
>
> Blood powers were not a certain thing. It was known which hereditary
> blood abilities ran within each line, but there was no way of predicting
> which ones would be inherited by any given offspring. The potential for
> all the blood abilities that ran within the line was there, but some
> remained latent, to be passed on and perhaps manifested by the
> succeeding generation. Some manifested themselves shortly
> after puberty, while others could remain latent for years, dormant until
> they suddenly manifested without warning.

One of the powers is *divine wrath*, occasionally referred to as *divine rage* but mostly as *divine wrath*. It is a very rare power as you describe:

> Among all the powers that had passed down to the blooded from the old
> gods, divine wrath was the rarest and most dangerous, for once it was
> unleashed, there was no stopping it until it ran its course. Those who
> had it used it only as a last resort, and only in the most dire
> extremities because it was a power that possessed its wielder
> absolutely, releasing the feral beast within and magnifying it many
> times. It turned a human into a raging berserker incapable of rational
> thought or self-control, bent only on mayhem and survival.

However the *divine wrath* doesn't fit your description exactly since it's really just a form of enhanced berserker rage and there is nothing in the book about projecting your blood lust across the battlefield.

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that this is a *Dungeons & Dragons* novel, in the *Birthright* setting.  I've never read the book; however, the game rules for the *divine wrath* ability include a *fear* effect emanating from the scion who is using it.